# Screen Flashing with Dynamically Created UIButton compared to UILabel when Searching in a Table View Controller

Tags: ios, uibutton, uilabel, uisearchbar, dynamically-generated

I have a simple table view controller which has a search bar at the top. The user starts typing in and if no results are found, I display a UIButton that I have programmatically created.

The strange aspect is the fact that if I use a UIButton, with every letter I type, the screen refreshes and you can see the text of the button flashing up again. It's very noticeable and not smooth. So a user types in one letter and it says "Click here to Create", etc.. but with each letter I type, that text seems to get re-rendered.

However, if I do the exact same with a UILabel, it does not re-render with each typed letter and is very smooth.

The reason I'm using a button is because if the name that the user is typing does not exist, clicking this button will create the name for the user. I assume I cannot call a selector for a UILabel, or can I?

Here's the code I'm using with the UIButton:

in

```
viewDidLoad:

    self.createButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    //self.createButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    self.createButton.frame = CGRectMake(-15, 90, 300, 30);
    [self.createButton addTarget:self action:@selector(createButtonWasTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    self.createButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.createButton.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = YES;
    self.createButton.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.createButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18.0];
    //self.createButton.opaque = NO;
    self.createButton.hidden = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:self.createButton];
```

In the method below, I'm dynamically creating the button if no results are found:

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    self.nameAddSearchBar.showsCancelButton = YES;

    _autocompleteFetchedResultsController = nil;
    NSError *error;
    if (![[self autocompleteFetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error])
    {
        // Handle Error
    }
    else
    {
        [self.nameAddSearchTableView reloadData];
        [self.createButton setHidden:_autocompleteFetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects.count > 0];
        [self.createButton setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Click Here to Create %@", self.nameAddSearchBar.text] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
... more code
}
```

The selector for the button is calling:

```
- (void)createButtonWasTapped:(id)sender
{
    self.selectedName = self.nameAddSearchBar.text;
    [self.delegate nameTextFieldTableViewController:self didSelectCell:self.selectedName];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

I could not find a way to call a selector from a UILabel, but if I can, that will solve my issues. If I cannot, I need to understand why with each typed letter, my "button" is re-rendering.

Any assistance would be really helpful!
Thanks,

Comment: try to set text first, and then set button visible?

Comment: Hi Alex - thanks for the message; unfortunately that did not work.. any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This was a very easy fix.

I changed the button type from Rounded Rect to Custom:

```
self.createButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
```

.. and with this change, the flickering stopped! Strange, but it's perfectly fine with me!

Comment: I had this issue with an unwind segue with custom animation and a custom UIButton set up in Storyboard. But I also had to "Reset Content and Settings..." on the Simulator for the change to take hold.

Comment: Weirdly, at least in XCode 7.1.1, I'm also having to "Reset Content and Settings..." on the Simulator (or just quit it and restart it) EVERY time I switch to a different device.